# Unable to push in remote git repo

Tags: git

i am trying to pust it in  the remote git repos and I got error message. Like Unable to push in remote git repo

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wo3G.png

Would anyone give step-by-step guide? thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have permission to push a commit since youre logged in as another user than the account that remote is on. If you are Smapang, change your remote to `https://Smapang@github.com/Smapang/Coursera-Test-Website.git/`

```
git remote set-url origin https://Smapang@github.com/Smapang/Coursera-Test-Website.git/
```

Now try to do a push and it'll ask you to enter your password for your account Smapang.

Comment: By the way, it is my repo and I tried that before and it does not prompt me to  enter the password. It does't give me any error messages too rather it send to send to same directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are contributing to this repo and it is not owned by you, then you might want to 'fork' the repository into your account and then 'clone' it locally.
That way you can do a `git push origin` to push code to your fork on github.
Then you raise a Pull Request from your fork to the original repository to be reviewed and merged by the owner of the repository.